# Как подписать картинку на CLICK?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Код index.html -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyTest</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="img/rect.jpg" height="337" width="344">
</body>
</html>
```

Как мне в файле main.js обращаться к картинке и как её подписать на клик?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- С jquery http://jsfiddle.net/JdUa9/
- Без jquery http://jsfiddle.net/jXUh2/
- Без jquery (2 вариант) http://jsfiddle.net/wULRV/

Comment: @alvoro: Спасибо Вам! И у меня ещё один маленький вопросик - можно как-то добавить картинке имя или id чтобы обращаться уже по ним?

Comment: Да, конечно. Используйте атрибуты class и id.

Comment: И чем отличаются варианты без jquery? Просто для меня второй способ ближе, но наверняка есть подвох с работай в разных браузерах?

Comment: Подвох [есть](http://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#кроссбраузерный-способ-назначения-обработчиков). Используя первый способ без jquery, вы можете назначить только один обработчик.

Comment: @alvoro: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста)